# how to call a dotnet main class from a cmd file

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd

i have a static void main method in C#. how do i call it from a cmd file ?
i created a file, but when i try to execute it just prints the lines in the cmd file
.

```
namespace dotnetclasstobecalled
    internal class program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
```

cmd file:

```
@echo off
dotnetclasstobecalled arg1 arg2
REM this is a comment
```

Error is "dotnetclasstobecalled is not recognized as an internal or externaal command"
i am calling the cmd file from the directory "dotnetclasstobecalled"

Sorry , this might be a trivial thing, but i dont have any idea how cmd to dotnet works,

thanks

Comment: The simplest option is probably to just use `dotnet run -p path-to-project-directory`. (Where `path-to-project-directory` is the path to the directory containing the project, obviously...)

Answer (score 1):

You can embed a c# directly into your batch file by using the .net compiler or msbuild

with the compiler (it creates an exe file)

```
// 2>nul||@goto :batch
/*
:batch
@echo off
setlocal

:: find csc.exe
set "csc="
for /r "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\" %%# in ("*csc.exe") do  set "csc=%%#"

if not exist "%csc%" (
   echo no .net framework installed
   exit /b 10
)

if not exist "%~n0.exe" (
   call %csc% /nologo /w:0 /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~dpsfnx0" || (
      exit /b %errorlevel% 
   )
)
%~n0.exe %*
endlocal & exit /b %errorlevel%

*/

using System;



class Example
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("C#!!");
  }
}
```

The msbuild inline tasks are compiled directly into the memory but the code is a little bit more verbose and you need to inherit the itask interface:

```
<!-- :
    @echo off


        echo -^- FROM BATCH

        set "CMD_ARGS=%*"
        ::::::  Starting C# code :::::::
        :: searching for msbuild location
        for /r "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\" %%# in ("*msbuild.exe") do  set "msb=%%#"

        if not defined  msb (
           echo no .net framework installed
           exit /b 10
        )

        rem ::::::::::  calling msbuid :::::::::
        call %msb% /nologo  /noconsolelogger "%~dpsfnx0"  /property:"H=From C#"
        rem ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        exit /b %errorlevel%
      
--> 


<Project ToolsVersion="$(MSBuildToolsVersion)" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Program">
    <Program/>
  </Target>
  <UsingTask
    TaskName="Program"
    TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
    AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v$(MSBuildToolsVersion).dll" > 

    <ParameterGroup  >
         <Z ParameterType="System.String">$(H)</Z>
    </ParameterGroup>

    <Task>
     <Reference Include="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\System.Windows.Forms.dll"/>
      <Using Namespace="System" />
 
      <Code Type="Class" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
   using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
   using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;
   using System;
   
   public class Program:Task, ITask
    {
      public override bool Execute(){
         Console.WriteLine("Whoa");
         String CMD_ARGS=Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CMD_ARGS");
                        System.Console.WriteLine("-- "+"$(MSBuildToolsVersion)"); 
         return true;
      }
   }
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
</Project>
```